# Laptop keyboard gets frozen randomly

Tags: keyboard

Keyboard gets frozen randomly without being able to recover on an Ubuntu 20.04 (upgraded from 18.04). I am not sure what is causing it since it could happen by using different browsers. I have noticed that normally happens when I am using a browser.

This is on a Dell Latitude E6520 with backlit keyboard and when the problem appears it is lit. If a plug an external USB keyboard (not wireless) I can type and the keyboard is recognized, maybe because it is loaded when anew device is plugged.

touchpad on the laptop is still working and the mouse pointer moves and works normally. Nothing else seems to fail, using the mouse pointer I can still clicking on the screen and select options, one of them is restart the machine every time this happens.

Anyway, how could I track what issue could have happened at that point?
What's the log file I could check to find out what happened?

Thank you in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `swapon -s` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Also `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, what is the model/maker name of your external keyboard?

Comment: @heynnema:  Here is the information: 

$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       1.5Gi       3.1Gi       381Mi       3.0Gi       5.5Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi

$ swapon -s
Filename    Type  Size Used Priority
/swapfile                               file     2097148 0 -2

$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60

$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
A06

Comment: @Sadaharu Wakisaka . The problem is with the laptop keyboard. The external keyboard works after the laptop keyboard freezes, but that might be that a new USB (external keyboard) was plugged.

Computer is a Dell Latitude E6520 laptop.

External keyboard is Dell.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema

Sorry I had some personal issues and couldn't check on this. I read your answer and I will work on that and let you know how it went.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIOS**

Dell Latitude E6520

You have a very old BIOS version A06 from 30 Aug 2011. BIOS A22 from 17 Jan 2019 is available [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=6434j).

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your Service Tag #

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS

**Update #1:**

Because your current BIOS is so old, you must update to version A08 first, and then A22. A08 can be downloaded from https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=K0T3Y.

**Update #2:**

This may, or may not, solve your problem, but it won't do any harm. We'll bump your /swapfile from 2G to 4G.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Comment: Bios was updated. Link to the page is correct to the A22. A08 needs to be applied before, though. I downloaded and applied, then A22.
I will be monitoring and posting if the issue is gone.

Thank you

Comment: @ubuntuUserNplus1 Good job on updating the BIOS! Let me know how it works out.

Comment: I upgraded to A22,  unfortunately, it didn't help with this issue. It still freezing after sometime. 

How could I trace the issue? is there any log I could check to see what is going with the keyboard?

Comment: @ubuntuUserNplus1 Well, it was important to eliminate the BIOS factor first. Please see Update #2 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: Hold on... I was trying after applying the BIOS update then next day when I booted  I got the system updates, which were several and applied them. Since then I haven't had the keyboard issue. I will keep monitoring this week and post if the problem appears again.
If it appears I will go for Update #2.

Comment: @ubuntuUserNplus1 You did just fine. BIOS update, then Software Updates. Please do keep me posted.

Comment: @ubuntuUserNplus1 Status please...

Comment: @ubuntuUserNplus1 Status please...

Comment: I have been using my laptop these last weeks and the issue seems to be resolved. It was the BIOS update and then the Updates pop up notification appeared and I applied all of them, restarted the machine and since then no keyboard freezing. I just applied new updates after that last set and no problems.
I think the BIOS was the main issue. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Reasons: an old laptop input device becomes unusable?**

1. Drivers in the OS removed accidentally.
2. Hydrolysis
3. Electrolysis Capacitor failure

[image: blooted_capacitor]

Dell laptops around 2010-15 are quite well designed. I have two E6230s using since Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

#1 Happens rarely than others but if this happens we need to go back the version of OS when it worked and upgrade without losing the module.
#2 Cheap plastic is vulnerable to heat and humidity, it goes really bad in the place without ventilation.
#3 All the electric machines contains capacitors and especially electrolysis ones are easy to fail than other parts. It is inevitable but older electric machines made in Europe/US or Japan still works fine, e.g. HP-15C or CASIO fx-260. Some electrolysis capacitors are badly made in particular places/companies.

My E6230 went through all these and last year one stormy day, I forgot left it connected to the outlet and it got lightning surge a little bit. `Esc` and `Right click` buttons are dead since then.

You can buy a new computer, dude, I think Dell E7250 or Latitude 15 3550 are good, too. They are only 7 year-old...